# Polymorphic relations in Laravel 4 - morphOne()

Tags: php, polymorphism, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Im having trouble creating a polymorphic relationship between two models:

- **Upload**
- **Group**

Simplified version of **Group** Model:

```
use Cartalyst\Sentry\Groups\Eloquent\Group as SentryGroupModel;

class Group extends SentryGroupModel {

  ...

  /**
   * returns the logo (upload model) from this agency
   *
   * @return Upload
   */
  public function logo()
  {
      return $this->morphOne('Upload', 'uploadable', 'model_type', 'model_id');
  }  

  ...

}
```

Simplified version of the **Upload** model

```
class Upload extends Eloquent {

  ...

  /**
   * returns the polymorphic relationship
   *
   * @return Upload
   */
  public function uploadable()
  {
      return $this->morphTo('uploadable', 'model_type', 'model_id');
  }  

  ...

}
```

As you can see the **Group** model is actually an extended Sentry 2 Group model, which is intern an extended Eloquent model.

When calling the relationship in a controller as such:

```
$agencyGroup->logo->saveUpload('logo');
```

i get the PHP error:

> *Call to a member function saveUpload() on a non-object*

Any help with this?

Comment: try $agencyGroup->logo()->saveUpload('logo');

Comment: Have you verified that `$agencyGroup` has an `Upload` on the database? It seems like your are calling `$agencyGroup->logo` which returns `NULL` and then calling `NULL->saveUpload('logo')`.

Comment: if i have `$agencyGRoup->logo()` it returns an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphOne` although if i try `$agencyGRoup->logo()->saveUpload('logo')` i get a different error to before:

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::saveUpload()`

Comment: in my controller i have `Use Upload`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `logo()` returns a `MorphOne` relationship and, since there's no method called `saveUpload` defined o `MorphOne`, it redirects the call to its `Builder`, which also doesn't have the method and throws the second exception you are experiencing:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::saveUpload()

That behavior is expected and it's the way Eloquent works. That's why you should use just `logo` **without** `()` as you were trying in the first place.

Although, your `$agencyGroup` may not have a logo, which causes the `NULL->saveUpload()` I've mentioned and throws the first exception:

> Call to a member function saveUpload() on a non-object

Try simply adding this on your controller:

```php
if (empty($agencyGroup->logo)) {
    var_dump("There's no logo.");
    die();
}

$agencyGroup->logo->saveUpload('logo');
```

If you see the message "There's no logo", it means you should first create one logo before calling it's `saveUpload` method.

Comment: ok so i think you have me on the right track.. although i may be missing a fundamental principal of Eloqquent models:

by doing the following it should work?

`$logo = new Upload();`
`$logo = $agency->logo()->save($logo);`
`$agency->logo->saveUpload('logo');`

is that correct ? thanks!

Comment: I assume it should, indeed. It seems a bit weird piece of code, specially because I can't really say what your saveUpload method is doing behind the scenes. You should, of course, check if the `$agencyGroup` already have an upload if you wish to update it. Otherwise you can simply create a new `Upload` every time.